Compatibility with React Native New Architecture and Maesrto
I would like to confirm Maestro's compatibility with React Native's New Architecture (Fabric and TurboModules). As React Native evolves, tools like Detox have had some challenges with supporting the New Architecture fully.

Does Maestro officially support React Native's New Architecture?
Are there any known limitations or issues when testing apps that are built with Fabric and TurboModules enabled?

I couldn't find specific details in the documentation about this, and I want to ensure a smooth integration for my project.
Thanks
